# Bootstrap Glyph icon Calendar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker, glyph

I have used a bootstrap Glyph calendar icon for a date picker textbox in C#. When the calendar icon is clicked, calendar is shown, but without the next/ previous month/year ARROW Buttons. There is a blank space instead of the either side arrow buttons, but still the arrow control works.

Does anyone know how to make the arrow visible ? I have used Knockout JS also.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you're implementing you may need to include the glyphicons separately, either use Bootstrap icons or something like Font Awesome.

Comment: There is a CSS Styling page also for the date picker calendar. Should i change anything in that ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, just adjust the appearance with classes in your markup.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Changed the default arrow with  glyph circle  arrows  and now it works fine.